# Login loop after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: login, radeon, 20.04, amd-graphics, gdm

I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. And after it I cannot be able to login desktop enviroment.
My graphic card:

```
[22:49:33@0] [ardaorkin@ardaorkin-Inspiron-3585:~]$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15dd] (rev c4)
```

gdm service running on the machine.
There is no .Xauthority file on the users home path.
I can able to login with recovery mode.
Please help me!

Comment: I've got the same issue, my lspci differs only that my rev is c3 instead of c4. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I solved it.
I upgrade to 20.10 recently and then I've still got same problem. So, I digged into deeper and the solution was to create an xorg.conf with *sudo X -configure* command.
Then I moved this file as /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Reboot the machine.
And it solved!
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I upgrade to 20.10 recently and then I've still got same problem. So, I digged into deeper and the solution was to create an xorg.conf with sudo X -configure command. Then I moved this file as /etc/X11/xorg.conf Reboot the machine. And it solved! Hope it will help you.